# How much notice is required if a company sacks a temp before the contract is over?

Tags: termination, contractors, legal, australia

I am on a 3 month contract, but now the company says they can not afford me and have hired someone else permanently to do my job (they couldn't hire me because of a clause in the agreement with the temp agency). How much notice (if any) should I be given?

Update:

The contract isn't finished yet. That's why I ask if there should be a notice period. I have been here for six weeks, and I have completed the task they had given me.

Comment: I would think it depends on your actual contract. What is written in there?

Comment: I'd say you dodged a bullet, there.  A company that is so close to the edge that a 90-day contract vs. W-2 employee causes this kind of concern isn't one you'd want to be at, anyway.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk The contract says I have to give 5 days of notice, but doesn't say anything about how much notice the company has to give.

Comment: @WesleyLong I know. I took this job because I am new to Australia and wanted to have some Australian work history on my CV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Australia accepts employment-at-will, as is generally true in the US, you can be dismissed at any time without their needing a reason. But hiring a permanent employee into that role sounds like an excellent reason to me.

You did nothing wrong (from what you've told us), this is just part of the experience of being a temp.

A 3 month contract with a temp agency just means they want you for up to that much time, not that they promise to keep you that long. The duration is mostly a courtesy to the agency so they can estimate when they should start lining up your next assignment of the contract is neither renewed not cancelled.

If you were working as a contracting business yourself, you'd with the contract to convert this contingency. As an employee of the agency, you just ask them to put you on another assignment.

On your way out, tell these folks that you've enjoyed working with them -- assuming you have -- and ask if you could use them as a reference. That's really what you were looking for right now anyway, right?

Comment: Yes I was looking for a reference. And I wasn't hoping this job would go permanent. I have also updated my question to reflect that the contract isn't finished (I have been with these guys for 6 weeks). And I guess the only thing I have done wrong has been to complete the job sooner than they expected.

Comment: In which case you should get an excellent reference, right? Sounds to me like you won.

Comment: Yes I will. I was merely curious as to whether a notice period was required or not for a temp position.